# mouseover with fadein effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im applying a fade in when a user mouseover a element, but is not working, here is my code line:

```
$(this.svgElement).on('mouseover', '.' + jsTagClass, $.proxy(this.onTagClick, this)).fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Crystal ball is broken—we can't guess your markup.

Comment: provide some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fadeIn in the callback function of your `mouseover` event listener like this:

```
$(this.svgElement).on('mouseover', '.' + jsTagClass, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

If the given variables have the right values, this will work.